# Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using an old php script and have an error with this query. Since I'm not experienced with mysql, I couldn't fix it.

```
"SELECT COUNT(p.postid) AS pid, p.*, t.* FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."post AS p 
INNER JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."thread AS t ON (p.threadid = t.threadid) WHERE
p.username='".$uname."'"
```

the error is

> Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

I hope someone can help me

Comment: I cant find any syntax error in your sql "SELECT COUNT(p.postid) AS pid, p.*, t.* FROM post AS p 
INNER JOIN thread AS t ON (p.threadid = t.threadid) WHERE
p.username='kamal'" I am using xampp on windows... My MySQL client version: 5.0.51a....What version you are using....

Comment: @Kamal: That's [MYSQL error 1140](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_mix_of_group_func_and_fields), and it's still documented even for MySQL 5.6.  But you're right, [I can't seem to find any way to reproduce it](http://www.sqlize.com/VUkSF3FEdE). (Although note that that query probably doesn't return what one might expect it to return.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error says, you can't SELECT an aggregate function, such as COUNT, without grouping rows either explicitly (using GROUP BY) or implicitly (by just selecting the aggregate). To put it in less technical terms - you're telling the database, "Look up all posts by this username, and the threads they belong to, and the number of posts", and the database is answering you, "the number of posts in what?".

So you'll need to be more specific. If what you actually want is:

- If you don't actually care about all the individual posts, and you just want the threads and the number of posts by this user per thread, remove the `p.*` from the SELECT, and add `GROUP BY t.threadid` to the end of the query.
- If you want the total number of posts as well as all the posts and threads, just count the result rows.
- If you want the total number of posts by all users in the threads you're selecting, that'll make the query much more complex, because you'll need to join on `post` again to get the total post count.
- If you don't actually want the count at at all, remove it from the query. :)