# Laravel SQL error with orderBy and count

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've suddenly started getting a weird error in my production environment with count(). The following two statements work totally fine:

`User::where('created_at', '2017-06-22 18::33:54')->count()`

`User::where('created_at', '2017-06-22 18::33:54')->orderBy('last_name')`

but if I try

`User::where('created_at', '2017-06-22 18::33:54')->orderBy('last_name')->count()`

I get the following error:

Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `created_at` = 2017-06-22 18::33:54 and `users`.`deleted_at` is null order by `last_name` asc)'

This doesn't happen in my local environment, and I'm not sure where to look for an answer in production.

Thoughts?

Comment: starting from mysql 5.7 the use of aggreagtion function and group by with column that are not in  group by is not allowed ... then check for you select ed columns

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547802/mixing-of-group-columns-min-max-count-with-no-group-columns-is-illeg

Comment: Why would you order something then count it ? This is a waist of resources.